# marshmallow - How can I map the schema attribute to another key when serializing?

Tags: python, marshmallow

I need to create a marshmallow Schema that is consistent with a given specification, in which I can not alter the key names. One key is the reserved keyword "from" in Python.

```
class TemporalExtentSchema(Schema):
    from = fields.String(required=True)
    to = fields.String(required=True)
```

This is of course not allowed in Python, so I need to write something like this:

```
class TemporalExtentSchema(Schema):
    t_from = fields.String(required=True)
    to = fields.String(required=True)
```

What I would like to have is:

```
{
    "from": "2018-01-01",
    "to": "2018-01-10"
}
```

Is it possible to map the instance attribute to another key (t_from -> from) when serializing?

Answer (score 9):

Use `dump_to`/`load_from` (marshmallow 2) or `data_key` ([marshmallow 3](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#specifying-serialization-deserialization-keys)):

```
class TemporalExtentSchema(Schema):
    # Marshmallow 2
    t_from = fields.String(required=True, dump_to='from', load_from='from')
    # Marshmallow 3
    t_from = fields.String(required=True, data_key='from')
    to = fields.String(required=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to achieve that, you need to overwrite **init** method of serializer class.
As i assume you are using ModelSerializer, this is how you can solve your issue,

```
class TemporalExtentSchemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TemporalExtentSchema
        fields = ('to', 't_from')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = kwargs.pop('data', None)
        fields['t_from'] = fields['from']
        del fields['from']
        kwargs.update({'data':fields})
        super(TemporalExtentSchemaSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

so to use this, just do the following

```
d = {
"from": "2018-01-01",
"to": "2018-01-10"
}

s = TemporalExtentSchemaSerializer(data=d)
if s.is_valid():
   s.save()
```

This is how it is achieved, i hope you understood, its plain code

Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention, that I use the marshmallow serializer. I guess this your answer is specific for the Django serializers?

Comment: Have you tried to overwrite __init__ in mashmellow Schema, it might work as it is also a python class.

Comment: Please don't do that. Use data_key/dump_to/load_from. That's a basic marshmallow feature.