# marshmallow - How can I map the schema attribute to another key when deserializing?

Tags: python, marshmallow

I need to have a "from" field in my marshmallow schema, but since it is a Python reserved keyword, I am unable to use the name.

Input data has "from" key and deserialized map should also have "from" key.
Stumbled upon [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51727441/marshmallow-how-can-i-map-the-schema-attribute-to-another-key-when-serializing) for serializing objects, but unfortunately `data_key` only accomplished the first part of the goal - processing "from" key from the input data.

How can I make the key in deserialized data have the target name?
Example schema:

```
class TestSchema(Schema):
    _from = fields.Str(
        required=False,
        missing='',
        data_key='from',
    )
```

Desired result: Python dictionary with key "from"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the `attribute` field parameter:

```
class TestSchema(Schema):
    _from = fields.Str(
        required=False,
        missing='',
        data_key='from',
        attribute='from',
    )
```

Excerpt from [Schema._deserialize](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/marshmallow/schema.html) method:

```
                if value is not missing:
                    key = field_obj.attribute or attr_name
                    set_value(ret_d, key, value)
```

[Documentation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.fields.html#marshmallow.fields.Field) for the `attribute` parameter only mentions it means "The name of the attribute to get the value from when serializing", but in fact it also means the name of the attribute for the output data when deserializing.